# Android Studio does not find TextView references (from the Design) in MainActivity.kt

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin

I'm completely new to Android Studio and something is not working for me in the Tutorial that i follow.

```
package com.example.ticktacktoe


import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import android.os.Bundle
import kotlinx.android.synthetic.main.activity_main.*

class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

        val allFields = arrayOf(f0, f1, f2, f3, f4, f5, f6, f7, f8)

    }
}
```

`f1..f8` and also `kotlinx` are all read and it tells me "Unsolved reference".

I have defined f1...f8 as id's of textViews in activity_main.xml

Example for Definition of f0:

```
<TextView
                android:id="@+id/f0"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="#FFFFFF"
                android:fontFamily="monospace"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Large" />
```

How do i solve this so i can reference m textViews from my design in my code?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Please replace your import line with synthetics to the following one:

`import kotlinx.android.synthetic.main.activity_main.view.*`

Nevertheless, please be aware that kotlinx synthetics for Android are about to be deprecated soon: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KT-42121. They are no longer a recommended practice, so it might be worth to check out [View Binding](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/view-binding)